# Serpent: неправильные раундовые ключи

Tags: key, шифрование

Здравствуйте!

Можно ли у вас спросить, правильно ли я провожу расчет раундовых ключей в шифрований Serpent?

Допустим, если изначально ключ будет таким:

```
15FC0D48 D7F8199C BE399183 4D96F327 10000000 00000000  00000000  00000000
32бита    32бита   32бита    32бита  32бита   32бита    32бита    32бита
w-8         w-7      w-6       w-5     w-4       w-3       w-2       w-1
```

как мы видим, ключ неполный, расширим его до 256 бит. Так же пронумеруем их (w-8, минус (от минус 8 до минус 1)).

```
wi=(wi-8 xor wi-5 xor wi-3 xor wi-1 xor phi xor i)<<<11
```

Далее запустим функцию выбора подключей, где phi - это 9e3779b9, запустим от 0 до 131 для получения 33-х 128-битных ключей.

Проведем расчет от 0 до 4, чтобы получить, 1 из 33-х раундовых ключей
`(k0,k1,k2,k3)=S3(w0,w1,w2,w3)` и так далее, до w131.

1) i=0

```
w0=w-8 xor w-5 xor w-3 xor w-1 xor 9e3779b9 xor 0<<<11=15FC0D48 xor 4D96F327 xor 00000000 xor 00000000 xor 9e3779b9 xor 0 <<<11=EC3EB632
```

2) i=1

```
w1=w-7 xor w-4 xor w-2 xor w0 xor 9e3779b9 xor 1<<<11=D7F8199C xor 10000000 xor  00000000 xor EC3EB632 xor 9e3779b9 xor  1<<<11=8EB0B5AF
```

3) i=2

```
w2=w-6 xor w-3 xor w-1 xor w1 xor 9e3779b9 xor 2<<<11=BE399183 xor 00000000 xor 00000000 xor 8EB0B5AF xor 9e3779b9 xor  2<<<11=F2ECBD75
```

4) i=3

```
w3=w-5 xor w-2 xor w0 xor w2 xor 9e3779b9 xor 3<<<11=4D96F327 xor 00000000  xor EC3EB632 xor F2ECBD75 xor 9e3779b9 xor 3<<<11=9C0ED66B
```

Для первого раундового ключа проведем его через 3-й SBOX:

```
S3(w0,w1,w2,w3)
EC3EB632
В бинарной записи:
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11 12 13 14 15
11|10|11|00|00|11|11|10|10|11|01|10|00|11|00|10|
После перестановки в Sbox3:
11101010001111001110110001101100
EA3CEC6C

8EB0B5AF
В бинарной записи:
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11 12 13 14 15
10|00|11|10|10|11|00|00|10|11|01|01|10|10|11|11
После перестановки в Sbox3:
10110110101100101000111001001111
B6B28E4F

F2ECBD75
В бинарной записи:
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11 12 13 14 15
11|11|00|10|11|10|11|00|10|11|11|01|01|11|01|01
После перестановки в Sbox3:
11010110011111101111001111001001
D67EF3C9

9C0ED66B
В бинарной записи:
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11 12 13 14 15
10|01|11|00|00|00|11|10|11|01|01|10|01|10|10|11
После перестановки в Sbox3:
10111011010111001001110001100010
BB5C9C62
```

В итоге мы имеем: `EA3CEC6C B6B28E4F D67EF3C9 BB5C9C62`

Первый ключ k0 должен быть 2958B648, у меня он EA3CEC6C после S3, и даже после IP он стал FAD796F1, что никак не сходиться с ответом. Может быть, я нарушил порядок нумерации, и w-8 - это самый крайний ключ, хотя везде написано, что начинаем нумерацию с w-8 до w-1. Пробовал проводить расчет вот так:

```
15FC0D48 D7F8199C BE399183 4D96F327 00000000 00000000  00000000  00000001
32бита    32бита   32бита    32бита  32бита   32бита    32бита    32бита
w-8         w-7      w-6       w-5     w-4       w-3       w-2       w-1
```

С ответом тоже не сошлось.

И даже если провести ключ w0,w1,w2,w3 через IP, то выходит

```
FAD796F1 A1F7DDB0 7D51EEB1 17C8762B
```

что не сходиться с ответами.

Не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, сказать, в чем ошибка? Заранее Вам спасибо!

**Обновление**

В Интернете отсутствуют какие-либо примеры тестовых векторов для всех стадий шифрования, есть только вектора PT/KEY/CT, тем самым невозможно сделать дебаггинг Расширения ключа.